# How to dynamically render the profile-view once deleting a certain item in the favorites-list to reflect the changes in reactjs app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, client-side

I am new to reactjs and this is my first project. I made a movies app myFlix, in which a user can register themselves, login, browse through the movies, add a movie to their Favorites-List, delete it from the Favorites-List, Update their account info and delete their account. The button to add a movie to Favorites-Movies is in the Movie-View component, after adding the movie to the Favorites-List, it appears in the Profile-View component if the logged in user, and if I delete that movie I have to refresh the browser page to see the changes in the Favorites-Movies list. I want to see the changes without having to refresh the browser. Also, the Update Information functionality is not working. You can checkout my app on here :- "https://my-flix-007.netlify.app/"

Here is the code for the ProfileView:-

```
 import axios from 'axios';
 import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
 import { Button, Card, Form, Row, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
 import './profile-view.scss';
 
 export class ProfileView extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
 
     this.state = {
       Username: null,
       Password: null,
       Email: null,
       Birthday: null,
       FavoriteMovies: [],
       validated: null,
     };
     this.removeFavoriteMovie= this.removeFavoriteMovie.bind(this);
   }
 
   componentDidMount() {
     const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
     if (accessToken !== null) {
       this.getUser(accessToken);
     }
   }
 
 
// get user method
   getUser(token) {
     const username = localStorage.getItem('user');
     axios.get(`https://my-flix-007.herokuapp.com/users/${username}`, {
       headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
     })
       .then((response) => {
         this.setState({
           Username: response.data.Username,
           Password: response.data.Password,
           Email: response.data.Email,
           Birthday: response.data.Birthdate,
           FavoriteMovies: response.data.FavoriteMovies,
         });
       })
       .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
       });
   }
 
 
  removeFavoriteMovie(movie) {
     this.setState({})
     const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
     const url = 'https://my-flix-007.herokuapp.com/users/';
     const user = localStorage.getItem("user");
     
     axios.delete(url + user + "/movies/" + movie._id, {
       
         headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
       })
       .then((response) => {
         console.log(response);
         alert("Removed from favorites");
     // this.componentDidMount();
       })
       .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
       });
   }
 
   handleUpdate(e, newUsername, newPassword, newEmail, newBirthday) {
     this.setState({
       validated: null,
     });
 
     const form = e.currentTarget;
     if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();
       this.setState({
         validated: true,
       });
       return;
     }
     e.preventDefault();
 
     const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
     const username = localStorage.getItem('user');
 
     axios.put(`https://my-flix-007.herokuapp.com/users/${username}`, {
       headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
       data: {
         Username: newUsername ? newUsername : this.state.Username,
         Password: newPassword ? newPassword : this.state.Password,
         Email: newEmail ? newEmail : this.state.Email,
         Birthday: newBirthday ? newBirthday : this.state.Birthday,
       },
     })
       .then((response) => {
         alert('Saved Changes');
         this.setState({
           Username: response.data.Username,
           Password: response.data.Password,
           Email: response.data.Email,
           Birthday: response.data.Birthday,
         });
         localStorage.setItem('user', this.state.Username);
         window.open(`/users/${username}`, '_self');
       })
       .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
       });
   }
 
   setUsername(input) {
     this.Username = input;
   }
 
   setPassword(input) {
     this.Password = input;
   }
 
   setEmail(input) {
     this.Email = input;
   }
 
   setBirthday(input) {
     this.Birthday = input;
   }
 
   handleDeleteUser(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
 
     const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
     const username = localStorage.getItem('user');
 
     axios.delete(`https://my-flix-007.herokuapp.com/users/${username}`, {
       headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
     })
       .then(() => {
         localStorage.removeItem('user');
         localStorage.removeItem('token');
         alert('Your account has been deleted.');
         window.open(`/`, '_self');
       })
       .catch((e) => {
         console.log(e);
       });
   }
 
   stateChange(e){
      this.setState({
       FavoriteMovies: e.target.value
     });
   }
   render() {
     const { FavoriteMovies, validated } = this.state;
     const { movies } = this.props;
 
     return (
       <Container className="parentContainer">
       <Row className="profile-view">
         <Card className="profile-card">
           <h2>Your Favorites Movies</h2>
           <Card.Body>
             {FavoriteMovies.length === 0 && <div className="text-center">You don't have any Favorite Movies.</div>}
 
               <div className="favorites-movies ">
               {FavoriteMovies.length > 0 &&
                 movies.map((movie) => {
                   if (movie._id === FavoriteMovies.find((favMovie) => favMovie === movie._id)) {
                   return (
                   <div key={movie._id}>
                <Card style={{ width: '15rem', float: 'left' }} className='d-inline-flex align-content-start m-1'>
                <Card.Img className='favorites-movie p-2' variant="top" src={movie.Image_link} />
                <Card.Body className='movie-card-body'>
                <Button className='remove-favorite' variant='danger' onChange={this.stateChange.bind(this)}
                 onClick={() => this.removeFavoriteMovie(movie)}> Delete
                    </Button>
                     </Card.Body>
                      </Card>
                     </div>
                     );
                   }
                 })}
             </div>
           </Card.Body>
 
           <h1 className="section">Update Profile</h1>
           <Card.Body>
             <Form noValidate validated={validated} className="update-form" onSubmit={(e) => this.handleUpdate(e, this.Username, this.Password, this.Email, this.Birthday)}>
             <Form.Group controlId="formBasicUsername">
                 <Form.Label className="form-label">Username</Form.Label>
                 <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Change Username" onChange={(e) => this.setUsername(e.target.value)} />
               </Form.Group>
 
               <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                 <Form.Label className="form-label">
                   Password<span className="required">*</span>
                 </Form.Label>
                 <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="New Password" onChange={(e) => this.setPassword(e.target.value)} />
               </Form.Group>
 
               <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                 <Form.Label className="form-label">Email</Form.Label>
                 <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Change Email" onChange={(e) => this.setEmail(e.target.value)} />
               </Form.Group>
 
               <Form.Group controlId="formBasicBirthday">
                 <Form.Label className="form-label">Birthday</Form.Label>
                 <Form.Control type="date" placeholder="Change Birthday" onChange={(e) => this.setBirthday(e.target.value)} />
               </Form.Group>
 
               <Button variant='danger' type="submit">
                 Update
               </Button>
 
               <h3>Delete your Account</h3>
               <Card.Body>
                 <Button variant='danger' onClick={(e) => this.handleDeleteUser(e)}>
                   Delete Account
                 </Button>
               </Card.Body>
             </Form>
 
           </Card.Body>
         </Card>
         </Row >
         </Container>
     );
   }
 }
 
 ProfileView.propTypes = {
   user: PropTypes.shape({
     FavoriteMovies: PropTypes.arrayOf(
       PropTypes.shape({
         _id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
         Title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
       })
     ),
     Username: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
     Email: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
     Birthday: PropTypes.string,
   }),
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the state after to see any change in the UI.

Example:

```js
removeFavoriteMovie(movie) {
  .
  .
  .
  axios.delete(url + user + "/movies/" + movie._id, {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        })
      .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          const index = FavoriteMovies.findIndex(x => x._id === movie._id);
          this.setState({
              FavoriteMovies: [...FavoriteMovies.splice(index, 1)]
          });
}
```

Comment: But reactjs component have the property that they render themselves everytime the state changes. Is it possible that I can use that property to render the updated movie list?

Comment: @AnjaliTyagi That is correct. But you need to update the FavoriteMovies state with removed movie too to see the UI update. I'll update my answer too.